# WprdPress Custom Post Type - how to display data on Popup or Sidebar

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a custom post type called "team-member" which is in relationship (using ACF) with another custom post type called "speciality".
I have wrote the code to display team member on the page, team member name and speciality and all works perfect.
All the team members have also own description, so I would like to display the team member title, description and speciality within the Popup.

This is the code I have so far:

```
$relatedTeamMembers = new WP_Query(array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'team-member',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'related_team_group',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
        'value' => '130'
    )
    )
));

if ($relatedTeamMembers->have_posts()) {
    echo '<div class="team-members wrapper wrapper--larger">';
    echo '<h2>OUR DENTISTS</h2>';
    echo '<div class="team-members__wrapper">';
        while($relatedTeamMembers->have_posts()) {
            $relatedTeamMembers->the_post(); ?>
                <div class="team-member">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">
                        <img class="team-member__image" src="<?php
                            if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
                                the_post_thumbnail_url('teamMemberPortrait');
                                } else {
                                echo get_theme_file_uri('img/placeholder.png');
                        } ?> ">
                    </a>
                    <div class="team-member__label-gold">
                        <div class="team-member__label-gold__name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                        <div class="white-underline-strip-h-thin"></div>
                        <div class="team-member__label-gold__speciality"><?php
                            $specialities = get_field('related_speciality');
                            foreach($specialities as $specialities);
                            echo $specialities->post_title; ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php }
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

So looking at this pice `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target="_blank">` the target attribute behaves similarly, when the team member card is clicked it loads the data in the new window, I would like the same behaviour but instead the data need to be loaded within the popup.
My popup is done in JS and is using `injectHTML()` function as below:

```
injectHTML() {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `
        <div>Team Member Details</div>
    `)
}
```

But it I have no idea how to connect click event on the card member with the team member content.
I would be super grateful for a hint or correct way to achieve this type functionality?

Answer (score 0):

bind() can pass event when call injectHTML(). Then in injectHTML(), the member info can pass.
As primary these can be use:

1. Add EventListener() with  as, document.querySelector("a").addEventListener('click',injectHTML.bind(event));
2. Then, parse the required information by event.

Comment: Thanks, this looks very complex because even if I can inject HTML I won't be able to inject PHP into JS. Because as you see in my code there is 50:50 PHP and HTML code.